# Wordpress database connection error & Database was not shutdown normally

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I need some solution for my wordpress site database error. I have face this DB error last one month. I don't know what is the reason for this Database connection error. Please review my error.log provide your succession.

```
    2018-06-19 15:59:15 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 50223779105 and 50223779105 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 50225310342 in the ib_logfiles!
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
```

Comment: You can add the following entry to your /etc/my.cnf file (assuming you are using MySQL 5.6): `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1`

Comment: Is this problem coming every time you try to connect your website or in the middle of doing something on your website ?

Comment: Hi @Ash-b Thanks reply. I will add check it. Please let me know that is the reason for DB connection error (sometime)  & shutdown.?

Comment: @PHPWeb I have face this problem sometime . EX (1 day or 1 week). Currently my site in live. some time duration i face this issue.

Comment: @VinothRaja then the problem is somewhere else . Check your connection string , if possible reset your server (if the server is dedicated) or discuss with server people . If you still face this issue , create a clone in some other server and check with that .